# What is the effect using jquery ajax with auto request?

Tags: ajax, http, jquery, httprequest

I have auto request using jquery ajax, I am using this function for detection new chat message & notification case. Sometimes I am thinking again what is the effect if client auto request without finish,

I am worried my server is down because i think this is like DDOS HTTP Throttling.

This is my code

```
    $(function(){
         initChat();
    });

    /* 
     * initialize chat system
     */
    function initChat() {
        setTimeout("notifChat()" ,2000);    
    }

    function notifChat() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/url',
            type:"GET",
            data: {id:$("#id").val()},
            success:function (data,msg) {
                //to do success

            }
        });
        setTimeout("notifChat()" ,2000);
    }
```

My question is

1. Is possible to down server or make server hung up ?
2. If it is not better idea any somethink suggestion ?

Comment: there are many better ways to make this code more efficient. like what if something goes wrong requesting /url u should check to see that it succeeds and have a max retry request

Comment: [Everything you could ever want to know about your issue; more commonly referred to as "The Two HTTP Connection Limit Issue"](http://www.openajax.org/runtime/wiki/The_Two_HTTP_Connection_Limit_Issue)

Comment: @RPM can you give me some example...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is not production ready code, I have not tested it.

A couple weekness of this code:

It does not handle the two http connection limit

strengths:

it can tell if the server return an error (as in server error 404,403,402....)

```
var failed_requests = 0;
var max = 15;

$(function(){

     initChat();
});

/* 
 * initialize chat system
 */
function initChat()
{
     setTimeout(
             function() 
             {
                notifChat(); 
             }, 2000)
}


function notifChat() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/url',
        type:"GET",
        data: {id:$("#id").val()},
        success:function (data,msg) 
        {
            //to do success

        },
        complete: function()
        {

            // either call the function again, or do whatever else you want.


        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {   
            failed_requests = failed_requests + 1;

            if(failed_requests  < max)
            {
                setTimeout(
                         function() 
                         {
                            notifChat();
                         }, 2000)
            }
            else
            {  
                alert('We messed up');
            }

        }


    });

}
```